# Bind the DateTimePicker.Text to the DateTimePicker.SelectedDate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datetime

I would like to bind the `DateTimePicker`.Text to the `DateTimePicker.SelectedDate` in order to always use the `.SelectedDate`.

I succed to do the reverse ( binding `DateTimePicker.SelectedDate`  to `DateTimePicker.Text`), but no the `DateTimePicker.Text` to the D`ateTimePicker.SelectedDate` .

**Here is my XAML :**

```
<DatePicker x:Name="DateTimePicker_Date" SelectedDate = "{Binding this.dDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, TargetNullValue=''}"  />
```

Anyone know where is my mistake ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
   <DatePicker Name="MyDatePicker" Text="{Binding Path=ActualDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, TargetNullValue=''}" />
```

where actual date will be

```
    private Datetime mActualDate;

    public DateTime ActualDate
    {
        get
        {
            return mActualDate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {

                        mActualDate= value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("ActualDate");
            }
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // NotifyPropertyChanged will raise the PropertyChanged event, 
    // passing the source property that is being updated.
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, What is ActualDate ? I would like to bind directly the .Text property to the .SelectedDate property ( on the same control itself)

Comment: ActualDate will be a property in your viewmodel, which will be using NotifyPropertychange and this binding the control with that property and  mode is twoway. which means when you change the control date from UI it will reflect in viewmodel and when viewmodel has some updated value it will reflect the UI.